# My app works fine in android chrome but not in webview which uses default web browser

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-studio, webview, android-webview

I have written a webview app which opens a web url. However the experience is just like when I have opened it in the default web browser of my Samsung S3 phone (android ver 4.2) which is very poor (e.g. google map cannot be displayed). Is there a way to force the webview app to use other browsers that default one, for example using Chrome browser that i installed in my smartphone?

Answer (score 1):

With Android 4.4, the WebView was switched to be based on the Chromium project. Prior to that it was an Android's specific implementation of WebKit. With Android 5.0 the WebView is now updatable without OS updates through the Google Play Store.

https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview

If you want consistent behavior in your WebView across multiple versions of Android you'll need to include your own browser engine. Once such project is Crosswalk.

[What is a difference between intel xdk, appmobi, and crosswalk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22369358/what-is-a-difference-between-intel-xdk-appmobi-and-crosswalk)